# How To Check If Each Box Had A Value Entered In It?

Tags: php

My first page has two boxes for the month and day of the users birthday, and on this page I want to go through and ensure that both boxes were filled out, and if not echo out a message saying so. The problem I am having now, is that the message pops up every time even if both boxes had values.

```
<?php
$valuesRecieved = true;

for($v = 0; $v < sizeof($_POST); $v++)
{
   if(!(isset($_POST[$v]))
   {
      $valuesRecieved = false;
      break;
   }
}
if(!$valuesRecieved)
{
  echo "You must enter a value for each box. Please click your browsers back button, and try again.";
}

?>
```

Comment: What's `$allEntered` ?

Comment: Send us the HTML?

Comment: Sorry working on two things at once, just updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your main problem is that you do the final check on `$allEntered` instead of `$valuesReceived` - so if you change `$allEntered` to `$valuesReceived` - you should be good.

But you should also consider the following:

Unless your form checkboxes are named numerically, AND those two inputs are your ONLY ones, your loop will not work properly. You should use a `foreach` loop, instead.

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if(empty($value)){
        $valuesReceived = FALSE
    }
}
```

Furthermore, if someone were to modify your client-side code, they could bypass this^ logic via deleting something from your form. So if you want to make sure everything is filled in, then you need to explicitly name what you're looking for like so:

```
    foreach(array("bday_month","bday_day") as $value){
   // the values in this ^array should correlate 
   // with the names of your form inputs
        if(empty($_POST[$value])){ 
            $valuesRecieved = False
        }
    }
```